# SpringBoot Load profile properties from classpath

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, datasource

**My Question:**

It is possible to load an configuration **application-persist.yml** from the classpath during startup?

The **application-persist.yml** is part of my external lib and contains the spring.datasource configuration

```
myexternallib.jar
- config
  - application-persist-dev.yml
    spring:
      datasource:
        jdbc-url: url-to-dev-database
        username: xxx
        password: xxx
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  - application-persist-prod.yml
    spring:
      datasource:
        jdbc-url: url-to-prod-database
        username: xxx
        password: xxx
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

In my spring boot project the myexternallib.jar is included as a dependency
and I want to load the configuration from classpath:

The **application.yml** of my project:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: persist
    active: dev, persist-dev
```

The Problem is: When i start my application, the Startup failed with an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

because the application-persist-dev.yml is not read correctly during startup.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Boot's reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) is very clear at this point:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/application-persist.yml
```

Comment: Spring loads properties from classpath /config by default. So there is no need to configure a specific location. My yml-file is in the class path, so it should load. Isn't it?